# $X - Y$ in a finite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Question: The domain is the power set of a finite set. $X$ is related to $Y$ if $X - Y$ is not empty. Is it a partial or strict order? If it is a partial order or strict order, is it also a total order?

I don't quite understand this. Can anyone explain it to me in simple terms? Does $X - Y$ mean an element $X$ subtracted by an element $Y$?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) on relations has a nice introduction (I recommend you read until Section 1.1). Then you can look at the page on [Partial Orders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition) to see the definition. $X-Y$ denotes difference of sets: $X-Y=\left\{x\in X:x\not\in Y\right\}$. This question can be reformulated (more formally) as: "Let $A$ be a finite set and $B$ the power set of $A$. For $X,Y\in B$, write $X\sim Y$ is $X-Y$ is nonempty. Is $\sim$ a partial, or strict, order, and if so is it total?"

Comment: Thanks! I will go over it.

Answer (score 1):

The question means the following:

> Let $S$ be some set. Let $P$ be the power set of $S$; that is, let $P=\mathcal{P}(S)$. Thus, elements of $P$ are themselves subsets of $S$.
>
> Given any two $X,Y\in P$, we can define their set difference $Y-X\in P$ to be this subset of $S$:
>   $$Y-X=\{s\in S: s\in Y\text{ and }s\notin X\}$$
>
> Define a relation $\mathsf{R}$ on $P$ (in other words, a subset $\mathsf{R}\subseteq P^2$) as follows: given $X,Y\in P$, 
>   $$X\;\mathsf{R}\;Y\iff \text{the set }Y-X\text{ is not empty}$$
>
> 1. Figure out if $\mathsf{R}$ is a partial order, i.e., whether
>
>    - for all $X\in P$, we have that $X \;\mathsf{R}\; X$
>    - for all $X,Y\in P$, we have that if $X \;\mathsf{R}\; Y$ and $Y \;\mathsf{R}\; X$, then $X=Y$
>    - for all $X,Y,Z\in P$, we have that if $X \;\mathsf{R}\; Y$ and $Y \;\mathsf{R}\; Z$, then $X \;\mathsf{R}\; Z$
> 2. Figure out if $\mathsf{R}$ is a strict order, i.e., whether
>
>    - for all $X\in P$, it is **false** that $X \;\mathsf{R}\; X$
>    - for all $X,Y\in P$, we have that if $X \;\mathsf{R}\; Y$, then it is **false** that $Y \;\mathsf{R}\; X$
>    - for all $X,Y,Z\in P$, we have that if $X \;\mathsf{R}\; Y$ and $Y \;\mathsf{R}\; Z$, then $X \;\mathsf{R}\; Z$
> 3. If $\mathsf{R}$ is either a partial or strict order, figure out if $\mathsf{R}$ is a total order, i.e., whether
>
>    - for all $X,Y\in P$, either $X\;\mathsf{R}\; Y$ or $Y\;\mathsf{R}\; X$

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the problem. So this is a strict order and a total order, am I correct?